# Using an iPhone as a Remote Video Recorder from a Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, software-recommendation, video, remote-control

Does there exist any app for iPhone/Mac that allows me:

- to see on the Macbook what my iPhone camera "sees" via WiFi?
- to remotely, from the Mac, start/stop recording on the iPhone?

I'm currently trying [iKeyboardRemote](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ikeyboardremote/id446670061?mt=12) but it allows me only start and stop recording via Bluetooth (and without any feedback). I would like to see when to start recording and when to stop.

I have found several apps in the App Store that allow remote video between two iPhones or iPhone/iPad, but found none for iPhone to Mac OS X.  (I don't have two iPhones, nor an iPad).

Unfortunately, I have upgraded to 6.1.3 on 4S, so I can't jailbreak it for installing a VNC server, which would be the easiest and best solution.

I'm hoping I missed some apps — can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: When you do get your second iOS device - [this is ultimate](http://motrr.com/galileo.html).

Comment: @bassplayer7 YES! This is really cool device.

Comment: You can use screen mirroring to view your screen on e.g. an AppleTV.

Comment: @AllDani, unfortunately, they kinda [went away](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://motrr.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be a handful of apps available that allow your iPhone to act as a webcam for your Mac over Wi-Fi, which would allow you to view and record video from them. A few of the ones I found:

- [PocketCam](http://www.senstic.com/iphone/pocketcam/pocketcam.aspx)
- [Mobiola WebCamera](http://mobiola.com/mobiola-web-camera)
- [iWebcamera](http://www.made-apps.biz/EN/Products/iPhone/iWebcamera.aspx)

For recording purposes, you may need to use the built-in recording functionality of QuickTime Player, although some of the apps seem to have free companion OS X software that will accomplish the same goal.

Comment: GREAT! Thank you, going compare them. :) I do not need recording on the Mac side - for me enough to record on the iphone side.

Comment: hm... jaggy on full hd - need something what will record into iPhone - and will transferring to Mac only preview.

Comment: I also need the functionality to preview on the Mac, but record to the iPhone itself. I want to have full 4K quality video from my iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is to connect your iPhone via lighting cable. Then you will be able to preview iPhone's screen on your mac via QuickTime -> File -> New Movie Recording (select iPhone as source).

That way you can see what is being recorded on your iPhone - perfect if you are recording yourself and want to somehow check if you are within the frame. It has some issues (can not start/stop recording via mac + portrait vs landscape issue) however maybe it will be good enough. It was better than anything else I found as 3rd party apps are (were?) laggy.